# grails publish plugin error "class not found loading plugin resource [spring.resources]"

Tags: grails, publish

When release a specific plugin that i've build, using "Realease-2.0.4" and Grails 2.0.1, I get a strange exception, which I can't seem to get rid of. I have many plugins with similar setup, and none of these produces this exception.

```
| Error 2012-11-15 17:00:25,604 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Class not found loading plugin resource [spring.resources]. Resource skipped.
Message: spring.resources
   Line | Method
->> 202 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   247 | loadClass in     ''
|   178 | doCall .  in _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure23
|   176 | doCall    in _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5
|    60 | doCall .  in _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2
|    45 | doCall    in PublishPlugin$_run_closure1
^    62 | doCall .  in     ''
| Error 2012-11-15 17:00:25,977 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Class not found loading plugin resource [spring.resources]. Resource skipped.
Message: spring.resources
   Line | Method
->> 202 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   247 | loadClass in     ''
|   178 | doCall .  in _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure23
|   176 | doCall    in _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5
|    60 | doCall .  in _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2
|    45 | doCall    in PublishPlugin$_run_closure1
^    62 | doCall .  in     ''
```

This is all there is to the stack-trace.

There are not resources defined under grails-app/conf/spring/resources.

Any idea how I solve this?

Comment: Any hook you tried to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.Context

I am using grails 2.4.3 and java 1.7 for develop one custom plugin and use it in an application. The custom plugin uses **spring-security-core** plugin and adds some functionality. The application uses the custom plugin and adds another features. The idea is setup spring-security and other common features in the custom plugin and use it in several projects.

When I run the application with next configuration at **conf/BuildConfig.groovy** file there is no problem:

```
...
grails.plugin.location.'author-security-plugin' = "../AuthorSecurityPlugin"
...
```

However when I packaged the plugin and installed it on my maven local repository with next commands:

```
$ grails clean
$ grails refresh-dependencies
$ grails maven-install
```

Using next configuration at **conf/BuildConfig.groovy** file:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    compile: ':domino-connection-lib:'
    runtime: 'postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1002.jdbc4'

    //custom plugin
    compile: "com.company:author-security-plugin:0.1"
}
...
//grails.plugin.location.'author-security-plugin' = "../AuthorSecurityPlugin"
...
```

And execute the ¨grails run-app¨ command, The project throws next exception:

```
| Packaging Grails application.....
2015-04-20 17:12:42,067 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Class not found loading plugin resource [spring.resources]. Resource skipped.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spring.resources
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at _PluginDependencies$_run_closure2.doCall(_PluginDependencies.groovy:48)
at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:57)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
```

**Note:** The **spring/resources.groovy** file contains:

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    customAuthenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider){
        springSecurityService=ref('springSecurityService')
        customUserService=ref('customUserService')
    }
    ...
}
```

## 2.Solution

The solution, in my case, was deleting the grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy file at custom plugin and move its contents to grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy at the application.

I hope this can help you.